# Angular : Paypal button won't appear twice without hard reload

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, paypal

I have a page with a paypal payment button generated in it : when I try to generate the payment button for the first time the button is displayed.

But if I try to generate the button a second time (to make another order on the app for example) nothing happens : the button won't display and I need to hard reload the page to make it work.

Do I have to "re-init", "reload" the paypal button or something ?

html :

```
[...]

<div id="payment">
  <h1>Paiement</h1>
  <div id="paypal-button"></div>
</div>
```

typescript :

```
declare var paypal: any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    [...]
}) export class OrderPage {

    [...]

    myFonction(){
        [...]
        // If the customer does everything right 
        // we display the paypal button : 
        displayPaymentButton()
    }    

    displayPaymentButton() {

        paypal.Button.render({
          env: 'sandbox', // Or 'production'

          payment: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.request.post(Api.API_URL + '/payment/create-payment', {
              bookingId: response.id
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.id;
              });
          },

          onAuthorize: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.request.post(Api.API_URL + '/payment/execute-payment', {
              paymentID: data.paymentID,
              payerID: data.payerID
            })).then((res) => {
                if(res.paymentState === "approved"){
                  // It Worked ! 
                  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                    message: "Commande réalisée avec succès !",
                    duration: 3000,
                    position: 'top'
                  });
                  toast.present();
                  this.navCtrl.push(MainPage, {}, {animate:false});
                } else {
                   [...]  
                  // Process Error
                }
              });
          },

          onError : (err) => {
              [...]
              // Process Error
          }
        }, '#paypal-button');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that even when the payment is over the paypal button still stay in javascript memory and generate another time the same button certainly cause problem.

As a hard reload work I find a work workaround while waiting to find a reel solution.

Replace this :

```
            if(res.paymentState === "approved"){
              // It Worked ! 
              let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: "Commande réalisée avec succès !",
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'top'
              });
              toast.present();
              this.navCtrl.push(MainPage, {}, {animate:false});
            } else {
               [...]  
              // Process Error
            }
```

By this :

```
            if(res.paymentState === "approved"){
              // It Worked ! 
              let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: "Commande réalisée avec succès !",
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'top'
              });
              toast.present();

              // ==> HARD RELOAD TO HOME PAGE <==
              this.app.getRootNavs()[0].setRoot(MainPage);

            } else {
               [...]  
              // Process Error
            }
```